# Is it possible to set up a sql view so that any joins are only performed when required?

Tags: sql, performance, sql-server-2008

I'm having some trouble with view performance. Specifically some expensive joins being performed when they are not required to be. I've managed to reduce the problem to the simplest case, and have used the AdventureWorks sample database to create the following view, which pulls together a persons name and email address.

```
create view PersonDetails_View
as
select P.FirstName, P.LastName, A.EmailAddress
from Person.Person P
left outer join Person.EmailAddress A
    ON P.BusinessEntityID = A.BusinessEntityID
```

If I run the following query against this view:

```
select FirstName from PersonDetails_View
```

The query that is generated is equal to that of:

```
select P.FirstName
from Person.Person P
left outer join Person.EmailAddress A
    ON P.BusinessEntityID = A.BusinessEntityID
```

In this query there is an unnecessary join being performed. I know why it is happening - If there are multiple `EmailAddress` entries per `Person` row, the results will be different. However in this particular case the mapping is 1-1, and always will be. Is there a way to prevent this join happening, so that the generated query is equal to the following?

```
select P.FirstName
from Person.Person P
```

(This simple case does look like micro optimization, but I have properly profiled and identified unnecessary joins in a view as a performance problem in my situation - I promise!)

Comment: Maybe you just should use the latest query (from person table, not from persondetails_view) for person data then? I would identify using persondetails_view in this scenario as unneccessary either ;)

Comment: Again, I broke this down to the simplest example that I could. I felt that posting a large sql view which joins upwards of 10 tables at a time would be needlessly complex for the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX ix
  ON Person.EmailAddress(BusinessEntityID)
```

To guarantee there aren't multiple matches.  That changes the plan.

**Before**

[image]

**After**

[image]

Comment: Thanks, that worked perfectly. For a followup, if EmailAddress did have multiple matches, but you performed the query in such a way that it didn't matter (eg. `select distinct FirstName from PersonDetails_View), would there be a similar solution?

Comment: @John - Looks like `create view PersonDetails_View as select P.FirstName, P.LastName, A.EmailAddress from Person.Person P left outer join (select max(EmailAddress) as EmailAddress,BusinessEntityID from Person.EmailAddress group by BusinessEntityID) A ON P.BusinessEntityID = A.BusinessEntityID` does the simplification but then the plan with `EmailAddress` included in the `SELECT` is more complicated.

Comment: Thanks again for that one. That does seem to do the simplification, but does make the query more complex. I'll have to profile some to see which option would work best for me.

Answer (score 0):

You can make this view as indexed view.Then it will imrove the performance and also there wont be join for every time you fetch data from the view.

Since indexed view create a separate physical storage for the result set of the join query one time and later whenever you access this view it will be same as accessing from a single table.

Comment: The underlying tables which are referenced by the view are updated so frequently, that indexed views would probably be even worse.